# How to generate PostgreSQL backup with QProcess, from the Qt app

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt, backup

I have the following code.
My problem is the following:
When I click on my button, I get the message, the backup was generated, but when reviewing the generated file, it is empty.
And the other thing is how I pass the server password in the arguments, because I have another postgreSQL instance that has a login password, I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
void Widget::on_pushButton_6_clicked()
{
  QProcess* process=new QProcess(this);
  QString prog("C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/bin/pg_dump.exe");
  QStringList params;

  params<<"-U"<<"postgres"<<"-v"<<"-Fc"<<"-f"<<"D:/base.backup"<<"monitoreo_db";
  bool res=process->startDetached(prog,params);
  if(!res){
    QMessageBox::critical(this,qApp->applicationName(),"Failed to execute command.\n");
    return;
  }
  QMessageBox::information(this,qApp->applicationName(),"backup was created successfully.\n"+
                                                            QString::number(process->exitStatus()));
}
```

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that you use a QProcess to backup your PostgreSQL database?

Comment: Yes, because I want to do it from my application, or there is another way.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using? I want to give you a relevant answer.

Comment: Ok, I'm using PostgreSQL versión 13.3 and Qt versión 5.15.2.

Answer (score 1):

According to the PostgreSQL documentation each connection to a PostgreSQL database instance is its own process(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-threading.html). If you are applying a development pattern like read-modify-write, RMW, then I recommend the following:

1. At the time your application determines it is necessary to perform a backup operation, wrap this operation in a class.(Use the Q_OBJECT macro if you are not using your own threading library.)
2. Your DatabaseBackupOperation object instance will accept all the arguments required to open a connection to your database instance per: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html. Your object is a simple wrapper around the QSqlDatabase object.
3. The useful methods associated with your wrapper class are named something along the lines of:

`pair{QSqlError,string relevantMessage} startDatabaseBackupOp(string label,...)`

and

`pair{QSqlError,string relevantMessage} stopDatabaseBackupOp();`

The other args there are easy to locate at: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-LOWLEVEL-BASE-BACKUP. Specifically section 25.3.3.1 titled "Making A Non-Exclusive Low-Level Backup". Per the documentation cited ensure you connect to the database instance as a user with the rights to execute pg_start_backup, or a superuser. I believe this answers your question about how to pass in a password.

4. Before the methods listed above are called the instance of DatabaseBackupOperation should update an internal variable named something along the lines of databaseSize. You can get this information by running the following query:

`select pg_database_size('databaseName');`

5. Inside the definitions of the backup methods listed above you will simply execute the appropriate SQL queries as described at: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-LOWLEVEL-BASE-BACKUP section 25.3.3.1.
6. Backup operations, depending on the size of the underlying tables, can take a long time. You can check the progress of your database backup by running the following query every now and then during the backup runtime:

`select * from pg_current_wal_flush_lsn ()`

Clearly this returns the file offset of the running operation, specifically the content written to 'durable storage'.(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-BACKUP) Unfortunately this only allows you to return a backup progress estimate since the query listed above to return the size of your database is returned in units of bytes. I do not recall how this relates to the 'fileoffset' reported by the recommended query.

The recommendation above slots in very nicely in a RMW overall design context. I apologize if this overall design assumption is too strict. However, if you wrap it in a class as suggested, the recommendation may hold you over until you can define a more robust implementation for your application and design decisions.

The steps listed above are a recommended way to approach your problem. Please let me know if it works out. I will have time to test the recommendation later during the week.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will test what I quote in my code, thanks again.

Comment: Although from what I can read and see in the documentation you shared, pg_basebackup, makes a backup copy of the entire cluster, and what I want is to make backup only of my database, but not the rest of the server, anyway thanks for your answer, it was useful to me.